# Is there a function in Google Drive API to get if the file was downloaded or opened

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-workspace

I am trying to get a date and time when a linked file is opened in a shared link in Google Drive?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `Reports API` of the GSuite Admin SDK, with which you'd need to list the [Activities](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities), of type [Drive Audit Activity Events](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/drive). without a GSuite Domain, this feature might not be available.

Comment: Just in case, you also need to be domain administrator to use this API